# How to use bitmap headers in Python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, bitmap, header

I am attempting to convert a bitmap image file to grayscale and using the bitmap header method. I have the following code:

```
BMHEADER = bytearray([
66, 77,  # BM identifier
102, 117, 0, 0,  # size of file in bytes
0, 0, 0, 0,  # unused
54, 0, 0, 0,  # offset where the data can be found
40, 0, 0, 0,  # no. of bytes in DIB header from here
400, 0, 0, 0,  # bitmap width in pixels
296, 0, 0, 0,  # bitmap height in pixels
1, 0,  # number of colour planes
24, 0,  # number of bits per pixel (R=G=B=8 bits)
0, 0, 0, 0,  # no compression
48, 117, 0, 0,  # size of the raw data
18, 11, 0, 0,  # horizontal resolution
18, 11, 0, 0,  # vertical resolution
0, 0, 0, 0,  # number of colours in the palette
0, 0, 0, 0,  # all colours important
])
bmp = open(file, 'wb')
bmp.write(BMHEADER)  # write header
pixel = bytearray([0, 0, 255])  # blue, green, red
for x in range (400):
    for y in range (296):
```

I am trying to figure out how to setup the headers so that it works. I know I have the width and height correct but I am receiving the following error:

```
    0, 0, 0, 0,  # all colours important
ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)
```

Any ideas what values I should place on the line for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You have two values in your byte array that are greater than or equal to 256: 400 and 296. You must split them into their upper and lower byte. Instead of `400,0,0,0` you should use `144,1,0,0` and instead of `296,0,0,0` you should use `40,1,0,0`.

If you want to derive those numbers instead of hardcoding them, use:

```
400&0xff, 400>>8, 0, 0,
296&0xff, 296>>8, 0, 0,
```

This works for values up to 65535. Anything larger than that and you have to use a more complicated expression for the upper bytes.

To do this in a safer fashion look into the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).